# Set label title to top position stacked bar amcharts

Tags: amcharts, stacked-chart

How can put the title label above each horizontal column (2003, 2004 and 2005)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To move category vertical axis' labels to the right and over the graphs, just set [`labelOffset`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelOffset) to a negative number. I.e.:

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "labelOffset": -50
}
```

---

To move vertical category axis' labels inside the plot area and over the bars set [`inside`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#inside) to a `true`. I.e.:

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "inside": true
}
```

Comment: OK, I assumed "above" meant "over" it. Updating my answer now.

Answer (score -1):

Set "labelPosition":"right" in graphs

Below is the code that will help you set labels on top(right as per amCharts)

```
"graphs": [
    {
        "fillAlphas": 1,
        "id": "AmGraph-1",
        "labelPosition": "right",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "title": "graph 1",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "column-1"
    },
    {
        "fillAlphas": 1,
        "id": "AmGraph-2",
        "labelPosition": "right",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "title": "graph 2",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "column-2"
    }
],
```

See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT9bD.png) to apply label on horizontal stacked bar chart

For helping yourself out you can try things [live](http://live.amcharts.com)
-Regards,
Dhruv